# benchmark: "let i in x...y" notation - How to set i as u128?

Tags: benchmarking, u128

I'm trying to use the "let i in x..y" notation while benchmarking, and ran into a problem:

the line `let i in 10_000_000_000 .. 100_000_000_000` throw an error, as i is a u32, and my numbers doesn't fit.
How can i set i as a u128 ? I tried `let i: u128 in...`, `let i as u128 in...` every notation that came to my mind, and didn't manage to find a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Benchmark complexity parameters are always `u32`. Making them more than `u32` wouldn't make sense since they're designed to be iterated over to collect timing data for a linear regression algorithm, and you're never going to want to do more than 4 billion iterations of a timing algorithm.

But you can easily take a `u32` and turn it into a `u128` with a multiplier:

```
let x in 10_000 .. 100_000;
let i = x as u128 * 1_000_000u128;
```

Comment: Damn good idea !
I'll explain why i wanted a u128: I'm trying to benchmark a mint pallet, but the existential deposit was something like 10_000_000_000, so i needed to iterate from this to something like 100B.
I see now why its not a good idea, thanks for the answer !